# Nvidia prime integrated GPU shown as llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, nvidia-optimus

My girlfriend just bought a Dell laptop with Ubuntu and updated to 18.04. But I saw that in Preferences > About shows the "graphics" as llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256bits). "lspci -k" command shows that Nvidia MX150 is using "nouveau" driver and Intel UHD 620 "i915". Ubuntu additional drivers shows that Nvidia-prime (opensource) is being used.

I uninstalled nouveau (it still was showing in the additional drivers but Nvidia-Prime disappeared, so I selected Nvidia 390 and when I reboot it was using Nvidia drivers and showing the correct card name (and the Nvidia driver in "lspci -k", but when I select Intel in Nvidia-settings, after a long time and the app freezing, it tells me to reboot my computer and when I do it, changes back to llvmpipe and nouveau driver in lspci (I even uninstalled the f***ing driver).

The battery is dying with 2:30h (medium brightness and TLP configured) and it was supposed to last 4~5h, maybe it is related to screwed up drivers?
Thanks in advance, and sorry if I'm not being clear, English is not my native language

Answer (score 0):

For me (only integrated graphics) helped setting `i915.alpha_support=1`. Try using instuction below:

1. Run `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` (you may use whatever editor instead of `nano`)
2. Add `i915.alpha_support=1 nouveau.alpha_support=1` to the existing line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` after `quiet splash`.
3. Run `sudo update-grub`
4. Reboot

P.S. My backgound with this problem:

Initially I had a blackscreen after splash, so I had to add `nomodeset` (afterwards replaced to `i915.modeset=0`). Doing this I could boot the desktop, but it was rendered by LLVMpipe (software rendering using CPU capabilities).